# Tweaking Sophos Firewall SSL VPN config for high Throughput and low Latency

Tags: sslvpn, sophos

Sophos Firewall XG when connected to OpenVPN 2.3.8 (`i686-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [IPv6] built on Jul 3 2017`)

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
verify-x509-name "OU=Domain Control Validated, CN=*.domain.com"
route remote_host 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
<ca>
Bag Attributes: <No Attributes>
subject=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=XXXSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
issuer=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
auth-user-pass pass.txt
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256
comp-lzo no
route-delay 4
verb 3
reneg-sec 86400

remote xxx.xx.xxx.xx 8443
remote xxx.xx.xxx.xx 8443
remote xxx.xx.xxx.xx 8443
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 8443
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xx 8443
```

So by adding below config does it make any difference

```
cipher none
#;cipher AES-128-CBC
ncp-disable
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
push "sndbuf 393216"
push "rcvbuf 393216"
tun-mtu 8192
fragment 0
mssfix 0 #1360
txqueuelen 4000
remote-cert-tls server
auth-nocache
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
```

**Checking MTU**

```
netsh int ipv4 show int
```

**Enabling Jumbo frames**

```
netsh interface ipv4 show subinterface
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface “TheNameOfYourInterface” mtu=8192 store=persistent
Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty "TheNameOfYourInterface" -DisplayName "Jumbo*" | Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -RegistryValue "8192"
```

**Verifying**

```
ping `-f -l 8192 [host IP]`
```

Comment: I would suggest not raising your MTU so high. You're opening yourself up to more retransmits than you probably want to deal with, given the nature of the internet and how there are no guarantees with packet flow.

Comment: MTU on the physical interface is 1500, so your saying it is better to set OpenVPN TUN MTU to a value lower than the real MTU (i.e.,tun-mtu 1400), and MSSFIX to MTU-40 (i.e., mssfix 1360) @JesseP.

Comment: You have to find the balance. Too high of an MTU means more data per packet, which means more of a chance something will be corrupted and the whole packet will need to be retransmitted, meaning overall slowdowns.  Too low of an MTU means too many packets, which can be bad for other reasons.

Comment: In some guides and on some troubleshooting forums you'll see many people suggest lowering the MTU to something like 1300.

Comment: You really cannot decrease the latency, but you can certainly increase it by setting an MTU higher than the actual MTU. Packet fragmentation and reassembly are resource intensive, and that is what needs to happen when packets are larger than the actual MTU. You should really not mess with the MTU or MSS. Today, we have PMTUD to discover the smallest MTU in the path. Jumbo frames are non-standard, and you need to make sure that every device in the path of jumbo frames actually support the size you are trying to use, otherwise the frames are simply dropped.